# Avoiding requirement to type sudo ifdown br0 && sudo ifup br0

Tags: 14.04, network-manager

My network settings requires me to type

```
sudo ifdown br0 && sudo ifup br0
```

to kick it into life after a reboot. How can I avoid having to do this? My `/etc/network/interfaces` has:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp

bridge_ports eth0
bridge_stop off
bridge_maxwait 5
```

Comment: You should not have to as you have `auto br0`..you have used `eth0` as `bridge_ports` and again mentioned `manual` Ip directive for `eth0`....remove the `auto eth0 iface eth0 inet manual` snippet and then have a check..

Comment: @heemayl Nope, that didn't work.

Comment: Do this `auto br0    bridge_ports eth0   iface br0 inet dhcp` and comment out all others..

Answer (score 0):

Remove auto eth0 from your  /etc/network/interfaces file.

Here's an example of a Proxmox VE host I have with bridged interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 123.123.123.123
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 123.123.123.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
```

Here vmbr0 is bridging eth0. eth0 is set to manual and doesn't start automatically, but vmbr0 does.

Yours then should look like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp

bridge_ports eth0
bridge_stop off
bridge_maxwait 5
```